# How SCons cache works with different OS and CPU architectures?

Tags: caching, cross-platform, build-process, scons

Is [SCons cache](http://scons.org/doc/latest/HTML/scons-user/ch24.html) safe for different operating systems and CPU architectures?

Comment: Yes. The cache identifier should be based off enough information to make the cache references unique per platform/architecture. If you see otherwise it is a bug. Have you seen any issues with this?  (also you probably mean "safe" and not "save")

Answer (score 2):

Across different operating systems, sure, but on the same operating system across different CPU architectures, no, not by default.  Last time I used SCons cache, (v2.0.1 of SCons) it was not safe across different CPU architectures.  That was the reason we stopped using it at my current job.  It can be made safe, by inserting the architecture into the build environment correctly, but it is difficult to get it to work right.

Unless every build machine on your network has the exact same hardware specs, I don't recommend using SCons cache, try getting clever with variant directories instead.  That can at least save you from having to rebuild everything when changing build modes.

Comment: This is surprising. I don't think I've seen any complaints about this from many multi platform and multi architecture build users on the mailing lists.  Sounds like you are referencing the compiler as "gcc" which no path, and that your command lines are exactly the same regardless of platform, and that you are writing the files out to exactly the same relative location to the sources?

Comment: I don't think I was very clear by what I meant with "CPU architectures".  The biggest problem we ran into was mixing intel and amd machines on the same network pulling/pushing to the scons cache.  Floating point fuzziness of resulting builds was then dependent on who first built and pushed to the scons cache.  I can see similar problems resulting from networks of build machines with mixed 32bit and 64bit architectures.  The build signature for a build on a 32 bit machine could be the same as one on a 64 bit machine, but the resulting object would definitely not be compatible.

Comment: So this was due to the compiler doing -march=native and thus optimizer spitting out code which was sub-optimal running on other manufacturers implementation of x86/x64 ?  So if you detect such and put -m32 -m64 and other on command line it should've been fine.  Basically putting the default into the command line. or even  -DMY_32_BIT_INTEL_FLAG which does nothing. Should be enough.

Comment: Also if you were writing 32bit and 64 bit out into the same relative directory to sources (an no difference in the command line) that would also contribute.  Usually I use variant_dir to specify per arch/build flavor and that (I believe) also resolve the cache dir issue.  If you run into issues like this you'll get help from scons users mailing list.

Comment: @bdbaddog, I agree, and we use variant directories with sub-directories for OS, 32/64bit, build mode, etc, but we still couldn't effectively work around the the issue of different processors compiling too different binaries when the processors in different build machines on the network were not identical. The only solution that worked was to have a variant directory level for the build node but that kills the advantage you are going after with the cache.  That's why my recommendation is to not use the scons cache unless all the build nodes on your network have identical hardware specs.

Comment: Can you grab the processor id into a string and then -DDONTUSE_CPU_ID="%s"  (CPU ID here)?  You just need the command line to be unique (for at least the files which matter here)  You shouldn't need a per cpu type unique dir.  The command line is included in the hash..

Comment: Yes, both that, and defining a variant dir level for cpu id works.  I like the variant dir level better since I like to keep build flags as clean as possible.  Either way, I stand by my original post.  If every cpu id on your network is different, you will not gain much with the scons cache turned on.  If every machine has identical cpu id's, go for it.